# How do you find the area of a triangle with sides $1.9$, $2.1$, and $2.5$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I can find the area of this triangle?

[image]

I tried to use trigonometry to find the area but I found no formula.

Comment: Try [Heron's forumula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula_) :)

Comment: Here you can use what is called Heron's Formula: it gives you the area of any triangle whenever you are given all its three sides. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: Have stated calculation using the formula ? where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Heron's formula, where triangle with sides $a, b, c$ and $s = \frac 12 (a+b+c)$ has area $A = \sqrt{s(s-a) (s-b)(s-c)}$.

Or you can use cosine rule to find the cosine of one angle, find the sine of that angle by using $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta =1$ and use $A = \frac 12 ab \sin \theta$ if you're more familiar with that.

Answer (score 2):

[image: areabyperpendicular]

Let $d$ be a perpendicular to an edge, and $x$ the measure of one side.

Then:

$$2.1^2=d^2+(2.5-x)^2$$

$$1.9^2=d^2+x^2$$

Subtracting bottom from top gives:

$$0.8=6.25-5x$$

$$x=1.09$$

$$d=\sqrt{1.9^2-1.09^2}\approx. 1.556$$

Area = $1.25d\approx. 1.94$.

This gives the general formula for the area of a triangle as:

$$\triangle=\frac14\sqrt{2(a^2c^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4}$$